# How can I make pandas columns consecutive by group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe look like

```
ID     Number
 1       2
 1       1
 1       4
 2       1
 2       3
 2       4
 2       5
```

Then, I want to create another columns called "consecutive number" looking like

```
ID     Number   Consecutive Number
 1       2              2
 1       1              1
 1       4              3
 2       1              1
 2       3              2
 2       4              3
 2       5              4
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `rank`

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('ID').Number.rank()

Out[50]: 
0    2.0
1    1.0
2    3.0
3    1.0
4    2.0
5    3.0
6    4.0
Name: Number, dtype: float64
```